# Where to place the greater than 0 in my excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get an average by summing then dividing by count but I dont want any cells with a 0 as part of the average.  Where should I put the ">"&0 in the following formula?

```
=IFERROR(SUMIFS(DATA!$G:$G,DATA!$K:$K,"B",DATA!$AA:$AA,"Male"),0)/
  IFERROR(COUNTIFS(DATA!$K:$K,"B",DATA!$AA:$AA,"Male"),0)
```

I tried placing in different areas and am not getting the correct average number.

Comment: `=IFERROR(SUMIFS(DATA!$G:$G,DATA!$K:$K,"B",DATA!$AA:$AA,"Male"),0)/IFERROR(COUNTIFS(DATA!$K:$K,"B",DATA!$AA:$AA,"Male",DATA!$G:$G,"<>0"),0)` - just add the condition to your `COUNTIFS` - btw: it does not make sense to set the denominator to 0 in case of an error - because that will cause an error as well

Answer (score 1):

In Office 365 you can simplify this a lot:

`=AVERAGE(TOCOL(G:G/(K:K="B")/(AA:AA="Male"),2))`

If you use actual range references (for example `=AVERAGE(TOCOL(G2:G999/(K2:K999="B")/(AA2:AA999="Male"),2))` ) that would improve efficiency.

If you want to exclude values that meet the conditions, but are equal to 0:
`=AVERAGE(TOCOL(G:G/(K:K="B")/(AA:AA="Male")/(G:G>0),2))`
I doubt you should exclude those though, as they do meet the conditions, so please explain why they should be excluded in the first place.

Comment: Good use of `TOCOL()` sir. Learnt something new !